# "Won't" or "Don't"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-difference

I wonder which choice would sound more idiomatic in my scenario below and why:

> A) Why...................you dance in front of us? Are you too shy? 
>   B) Yes, I am shy about performing in front of people. 
>   A) You'll never be a professional dancer if you are shy about audiences. 
>   B) Yes, I know. Someday I will have to get over my shyness. But not today.

1) won't 
2) don't

To me, "2" seems to be the best option, but I have seen most of the times people use "2", but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other context, "Why don't you [bare infinitive verb]?" would usually be interpreted as a casual, encouraging invitation:

> "Why don't you sit and relax for a while?"
>
> "Why don't you think it over for a few days, and get back to me?"
>
> "Why don't you show us some of your designs?"
>
> "Why don't you dance for us?" ["Why don't you dance **in front of
>   us**?" seems somehow coercive and strange, though.]

But considering the subsequent follow-up portion of the conversation, that is clearly not the intent here. I suppose that was the reason you included those extra sentences in your question: apparently the dancer has previously been invited to dance and has declined due to shyness. So this is a genuine question seeking an answer to the "why" question.

In this case, "don't" would not be idiomatic. On the other hand, "won't" [Why **won't** you dance in front of us?] does sound a little too aggressive for this situation. It casts the choice not to dance as a stubborn refusal ("I **won't** do it!") rather than a polite preference ("I **don't** really feel like it right now.")

So in this scenario, it would be better to use "don't", but in a way that is clearly information-seeking. In other words, not "Why don't you ...?", but "Why don't you **want to** ...?" Or even the more wordy (hence more polite/solicitous), "Why **is it** that you don't **want to** ...?"

In my opinion, however, the kindest, and most socially acceptable way to continue this conversation is just to drop the questions altogether, and change the subject. Something along the lines of:

> A) "OK, that's all right." B) "Yeah, I just feel a little shy right
>   now."

Comment: Thank you @Lorel C, it was helpful, but how aboylut saying: "**I just feel a little embarrassed right now.**"?

Comment: If that's how the person feels, then yeah, sure; the sentence is idiomatic & grammatical.

Comment: Thank you very much. And do these two sentences mean the same in this sense @Lorel C?

Answer (score 1):

My choice would be *will*.

**[Will](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/will_1)**

> used for saying that you are willing to do something or that you intend to do it
>
> *If you won’t tell him the truth, I will.  Who’ll help me in the kitchen?*

(MacMillan)

"Why won't you dance in front of us?" means, "Why aren't you willing to dance in front of us?"  Or "Why don't you want to dance in front of us?"

---

Edit: What about the "don't" option?

"Don't" could come across slightly more aggressive and confrontational.  Note that "dance *in front of us*" is already a bit aggressive.  Gentler: "You don't feel like dancing tonight?  Is everything okay?"

Comment: Thank you @aparente001, but what do you think? Using **"don't"** here, is something grammatucally incorrect or coceptually incorrect? Which one? I wonder if you could explain a little bit more. I mean using "don't" would make the sentence seem incorrect? If so then why?